# How to add new edges to the stellargraph dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx, stellargraph

I need to add some extra edges to Cora dataset using stellargraph. Is there ane way to add edges to the current dataset in stellargraph library?

```
import stellargraph as sg
dataset = sg.datasets.Cora()
```

For example in NetworkX, we can add some edges to the existing graph using `add_edges_from(edgelist)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it directly from stellargraph since version 0.9.
You'll have to use `.to_networkx()` to convert it back to networkX format, add you edges and then convert it back to stellargraph.

```py
from stellargraph import StellarGraph
import networkx as nx

g = StellarGraph.to_networkx(dataset)
g.add_edges_from(edgelist)
new_dataset = StellarGraph.from_networkx(g)
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into a similar scenario and converting back-and-forth to `networkx` format was not possible.  Specifically, since `StellarGraph` is supposed to be capable of storing graphs much larger than `networkx`, there will be a point at which converting would not be possible.

To get around this, I used [the `numpy` loading capabilities of `StellarGraph` 1.2.1](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/demos/basics/loading-numpy.html).

With `StellarGraph`, you can dump the edge array with `edge_arrays()` into `pandas`, then concatenate any desired edges onto that.  It is much lighter memory-wise, since `pandas` and `StellarGraph` both perform better than `networkx`.

Here is a short example:

```
import pandas as pd
from stellargraph import IndexedArray, StellarGraph

#### original data / graph

nodes = IndexedArray(index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
original_edges = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'source' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
        'target' : [1, 2, 3, 0, 2]
    }
)
original_graph = StellarGraph(
    nodes, 
    original_edges
)

#### new data

new_edges = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'source' : [3, 3],
        'target' : [1, 2]
    }
)

#### new graph

new_graph = StellarGraph(
    nodes, 
    pd.concat(
        [
            original_edges,
            new_edges
        ],
        ignore_index=True
    )
)
```